# How do I only get whois data for an exact domain?

Tags: netcat, whois

When I query a whois server with something like `google.com`, I get a whole slew of unrelated results, including things like `GOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM`. Here I'm doing it manually with `netcat`, but you get similar results using `whois`:

```
$ echo google.com | nc whois.internic.net 43

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

Aborting search 50 records found .....
GOOGLE.COM.AFRICANBATS.ORG
GOOGLE.COM.ANGRYPIRATES.COM
GOOGLE.COM.AR
GOOGLE.COM.AU
GOOGLE.COM.BAISAD.COM
GOOGLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
GOOGLE.COM.BR
GOOGLE.COM.CN
GOOGLE.COM.CO
GOOGLE.COM.DO
GOOGLE.COM.FORSALE
GOOGLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES
GOOGLE.COM.HANNAHJESSICA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HAS.LESS.FREE.PORN.IN.ITS.SEARCH.ENGINE.THAN.SECZY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.HK
GOOGLE.COM.HOUDA.DO.YOU.WANT.TO.MARRY.ME.JEN.RE
GOOGLE.COM.IS.APPROVED.BY.NUMEA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
GOOGLE.COM.LASERPIPE.COM.DOMAINPENDINGDELETE.COM
GOOGLE.COM.LOLOLOLOLOL.SHTHEAD.COM
GOOGLE.COM.MX
GOOGLE.COM.MY
GOOGLE.COM.NS1.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.NS2.CHALESHGAR.COM
GOOGLE.COM.PE
GOOGLE.COM.PK
GOOGLE.COM.SA
GOOGLE.COM.SHQIPERIA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SOUTHBEACHNEEDLEARTISTRY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.SPROSIUYANDEKSA.RU
GOOGLE.COM.SUCKS.FIND.CRACKZ.WITH.SEARCH.GULLI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.TESTZZZZ.3000-RI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.TR
GOOGLE.COM.TW
GOOGLE.COM.UA
GOOGLE.COM.UK
GOOGLE.COM.UY
GOOGLE.COM.VABDAYOFF.COM
GOOGLE.COM.VN
GOOGLE.COM.WORDT.DOOR.VEEL.WHTERS.GEBRUIKT.SERVERTJE.NET
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM
GOOGLE.COM.YUCEKIRBAC.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZNAET.PRODOMEN.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.LOLLERSKATES.RENDRAG.NET
GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.HAVENDATA.COM
GOOGLE.COMICTOWEL.COM
GOOGLE.COM
```

How do I **only** get the whois data for the exact domain `google.com`?

Comment: use the `whois` command

Comment: @Skaperen As I said in the question, you run into the exact same problem: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/5c04b3d56af92b910ad0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, but the solution may vary from whois server to whois server.

For `whois.internic.net`, use the keyword `domain` in your query:

> Often, the search finds more records than just the one wanted.  Specify 
>   both type and full name to look up a specific record (for example, 
>   `domain ibm.com`).

So, either of these commands should work:

```
$ echo "domain google.com" | nc whois.internic.net 43
$ whois "domain google.com" -h whois.internic.net
```

If that command does not work, query the whois server with either `?` or `HELP` in order to get details about the allowed commands:

```
$ echo "?" | nc whois.internic.net 43
```

Comment: I tested the `domain` keyword on `whois.name.com`. Unfortunately, it did not work, however, it doesn't matter, because any queries to the Name.com whois server only gives back results for **exact matches**, unlike InterNIC's partial matching.

Answer (score -1):

Why not the `whois` command itself?

```
whois google.com
```

Should get what you seek

Comment: Not on my machine: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/5c04b3d56af92b910ad0 (I still get flooded with all those "unrelated results")